# Where can I get blueprints of older aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, modifications

I'm currently working on a project for an internship that involves modifying a 1959 Cessna 150. I won't actually be modifying a Cessna 150, but it's more of a "if you did modify it here's how you would, what would happen, and what it would look like." I'm trying to convert it to hydrogen power. I found a suitable new motor and "replaced" the engine, along with removing the fuel tanks. I know I still have a bit more to remove, but I need a place to store the hydrogen and some other stuff. I could put it in the wings, but because hydrogen takes up a whole lot more room than the original fuel, I would likely need to store it somewhere else as well. I need to find empty space that I can store it in. Also, because the new motor is lighter than the original engine, the plane is now aft cg, so I want to avoid putting it in the back. I can't find the blueprints of the original Cessna 150 anywhere, and I don't have a real one to go off of. If possible, where can I find the blueprints/schematics (preferably for free, cause i'm broke)? And if I have to buy them, what's a good place to get them from?

Answer (score 2):

Blueprints and similarly detailed drawings for aircraft are not something that is generally available outside the manufacturer of the aircraft.

For a time, aircraft delivered to the US military were required to include full blueprints for every part.  I do not know if this is still the case.

I have been involved with a few WWII aircraft restoration projects.  We obtained complete sets of drawings on microfilm from the Smithsonian institution.  I do not know how we obtained them -- but there were dozens of rolls of film each with hundreds of drawings for each aircraft.

Even if you only had to pay for the cost to duplicate the microfilm, it would surely cost more than you are willing to spend and would likely take longer than the scope of your school project.

I suggest you talk with your professor about how they think you should progress.  What level of assumptions and details do they expect you to make?

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes a simple cutaway like the following ones should be enough ([source first cutaway](https://www.pinterest.cl/pin/403705554079504358/) and [source second cutaway](https://conceptbunny.com/cessna-150/)):

[image]

[image]

If you need a bigger version you can ask the editor or the owner of those cutaways.

As you can see, in the tailboom behind the firewall there's still a lot of usable space as well as behind the pilot and copilot seats. Obviously putting weight there is going to shift your cg but this is something that you are for sure already taking into account